# WinDBG ESP and EIP

Tags: debugging, windbg

I am trying to get to the bottom of an exception thrown in my application using WinDBG, at the start of the stack there is this:

```
04a4f25c 746fc477 System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback.PerformWaitOrTimerCallback(System.Object, Boolean)
    PARAMETERS:
    state = <no data>
    timedOut = <no data>
    LOCALS:
    <no data>
    <no data>

04a4f3ec 74b91b5c [GCFrame: 04a4f3ec]
```

I can see the ESP Stack pointers (04a4f25c and 04a4f3ec) and EIP Instruction pointers (746fc477 and 74b91b5c), is there a WinDBG command or anyway I can find out how this thread was started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

!CLRStack will show you the managed stack.  However, since this is a ThreadPoolWaitOrTimerCallback it's likely not to be in code you own.  You should investigate where you queue callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

From you call stack I assume that you are probably not looking at the thread that threw the exception. Have you tried issuing: `~*e !CLRStack` or `!Threads` ? This should give you information which thread holds the exception context. You can then switch to that thread using `~<thread_id>s` command and investigate further.